# Selenium Grid2, how to shutdown a node?

Tags: java, selenium, shutdown

I setup Grid2 with Selenium Webdriver and everything seems to be going fine but when a selenium test finishes, the node is still occupied and I can't reuse it !

Is there a way to problematically close/shutdown a node after using it ?

Thanks

Comment: what error do you see when u try to connect to the node again

Comment: I don't get any errors. I just wanna close the node after using it

Comment: the node is reusable as soon as the selenium test finishes.

Comment: That's my problem, it's still occupied even after the test finishes !

Comment: do you successfully quit the webdriver script once your tests are done? You could check the status of your nodes here http://your.remote.host:4444/grid/console

Comment: How do you determine that it is occupied? what do you and how do you confirm it

Comment: When I view the console and I hover over the used nodes, it says "executing..."

Comment: try running another script after finishing one.... and update your question with what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using driver.quit(); when the test finishes.